# Why am I not being able to split a String in java given that I have a string containing filename?

Tags: java, split

Basically there are some images in my folder called Patterns. All images are in `png` file format.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
import java.io.File;

public class IMG_List {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        File file = new File("C:/images/Patterns");
        String[] str = file.list();
        for(String f_name : str){
            String[] str_name = f_name.split(".");
            System.out.println(str_name[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

When i use the above code I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at IMG_List.main(IMG_List.java:11)
```

However when i use the following code i get no error

```
import java.io.File;

public class IMG_List {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        File file = new File("C:/images/Patterns");
        String[] str = file.list();
        for(String f_name : str){
            String[] str_name = f_name.split("png");
            System.out.println(str_name[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I not being to split the string with the dot ?

Thank you,
MMK.

Comment: Can you show a sample file name of the Images?

Comment: use f_name.split("\\."). It takes a `regex` as input. It fails since `.` is a special character.

Comment: The following are name of two of the images back_pattern, beige_paper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use escape characters  before dot in order to be re-presentable as a regexp since `split` function accept regexp

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```

use `\\.` in regexp to represent dot because `.` means any character in regexp

Comment: @MuhamadMuzahirKhodabucus no thank you for posting nice and cool question. : )

Answer (score 3):

The `'.'` character in regular expressions means *any* character, according to the [`Pattern` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

> . Any character (may or may not match line terminators)

So, you get a bunch of empty strings in between the characters.  But the [no-arg `split` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) discards trailing empty strings, and they're all empty, so you get a 0-length array, which explains the exception you received.

You must escape the `'.'` character with a backslash.  To create a backslash character, you must escape the backslash itself for Java.  Try

```
String[] str_name = f_name.split("\\.");
```

Then you'll get 2 elements in your array, e.g. `"C:/images/Patterns/example"` and `"png"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the dot:

```
String[] str_name = f_name.split("\\.");
```

Comment: thanks for editing - code section didn't work for me

Comment: I just formatted your post that is all. I did not touch the content

Answer (score 0):

If all the images are in PNG format, then you can also use  `String.substring()`

```
String st_name = f_name.substring(0,f_name.length()-4);
```